# How to do something else in Bison after Flex returns 0?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, c++17, bison, flex-lexer

> The Bison `yyparse()` function stop to read its input (file or stream) when `0` is returned.

I was wondering if there is a way to execute some more commands after it occurs.

I mean, is possible to tread `0` (or some *token* thrown by its return) in bison file?

---

Something like:

*Flex*

```
<<EOF>>      { return 0; }
```

*Bison*

```
%token start

start   : start '0' {
           // Desired something else
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose `program` is the top-level symbol in a grammar. That is, it is the non-terminal which must be matched by the parser's input.

Of course, it's possible that `program` will also be matched several times before the input terminates. For example, the grammar might look something like:

```
%start program
%%
program: %empty
       | program declaration
```

In that grammar, there is no way to inject an action which is only executed when the input is fully parsed. I gather that is what you want to do.

But it's very simple to create a non-terminal whose action will only be executed once, at the end of the parse. All we need to do is insert a new "unit production" at the top of the grammar:

```
%start start
%%
start  : program { /* Completion action */ }
program: %empty
       | program declaration
```

Since `start` does not appear on the right-hand side of any production in the grammar, it can only be reduced at the end of the parse, when the parser reduced the `%start` symbol. So even though the production does not explicitly include the end token, we know that that the end token is the lookahead token when the reduction action is executed.

Unit productions -- productions whose right-hand side contains just one symbol -- are frequently used to trigger actions at strategic points of the parse, and the above is just one example of the technique.